# How to make Django admin shows OneToMany instead of ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django admin page when we use a ForeignKey in a object, the admin shows the option to set a ForeignObject in the model that has the ForeignKey value.

For example:

```
class Diferencial(SobreFather):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Diferencial'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Diferenciais'

class DiferencialItem(models.Model):
    diferencial = models.ForeignKey(Diferencial)
    icone = models.ImageField(upload_to="icones_diferencial")
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.diferencial

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Item Diferencial'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Itens Diferencial'
```

This code will show the option to select a Diferencial object to be related to DiferencialItem in django admin.

Is there a way to show the option to create the DiferencialItem in the Diferencial admin view?

Comment: Take a look at [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [inline model admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
class DiferencialItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DiferencialItem

class DiferencialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DiferencialItemInline]
```